# Can I disable specific items in a PopupMenu control?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, user-interface

I have a `PopupMenu` in a `Manipulate` with items in it that are inapplicable in some cases, and rather than removing them, I would like to disable (just) those items that are inappropriate.

For example, I'd like to disable (not remove) everything in `list` that is, say, less than the item selected in `filter`:

```
Manipulate[
 {filter, list},
 {{filter, 1, "Filter:"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, ControlType -> PopupMenu},
 {{list, 1, "List:"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, ControlType -> PopupMenu}
 ]
```

Is there a way to disable specific individual items in a `PopupMenu`, without resorting to a custom control?

Comment: @Kuba: Sorry, pretty basic; added.

Comment: @Kuba: Better for me is `Manipulate`. And the above doesn't disable; should it?

Comment: @Kuba: Just says "too low". I can still click it, and it still looks enabled. Disabled == does not respond to clicks and shows disabled UI affordance.

Comment: Understood. But I'm not sure what do you mean you can click it. How would you describe not being able to click? :)

Comment: @Kuba: It should behave just as a disabled menu item in the hosting GUI behaves — e.g., on OS X, the item is grayed out, and the UI provides no affordance for clicking when the mouse is over the item: the cursor does not change, the item is not highlighted, and clicking produces no change at all (nothing happens). It sounds like the answer is actually "no".

Comment: I see, I'm afraid it is not possible to disable highlight of those elements.

Comment: @Kuba: In that case, I'll take a resounding "no" as an answer; and I'll ask a new question about a possible alternate approach that might work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to do this that conforms fully to UI guidelines (at least not for OS X). For example, your "disabled" items will still highlight as you hover over them and will still react to selection (thought they will do nothing).

This is as close as you can get:

```
Manipulate[
 {filter, list}
 ,
 {{filter, 1, "Filter:"}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, ControlType -> PopupMenu} ,
 {list, None} ,
 Grid[{{"List:", 
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[list, If[# < filter, , list = #] &], 
     # -> Dynamic[Style[#, If[# < filter, Gray, Black]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    ]
 }}
]]
```

[image]

Comment: Last time I delete my answer before fixing it +1

Comment: @Kuba - How did you get the picture of the popup menu activated into the answer?  I am using the SE Uploader tool and I am not able to do this?

Comment: @JackLaVigne Sorry for missing your comment! I just come here to check something and saw it. If you are still interested, I did a screen shot, pasted to nb, crop with crop tool, copy as bitmap and ctrl+v here. That is what I usually do.

Comment: @Kuba. Thank you. Sometimes have to wait for good things. 

Answer (score 3):

It's a `DynamicModule` not a `Manipulate`, but it works (Mma V10.1 on Mac and Windows)

```
DynamicModule[{filter, list = 1},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[filter], Range[6]],
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[list], 
    Table[With[{i = i}, (If[i < filter, list = list, list = i]) -> 
       i], {i, 6}]],
   {"filter", Dynamic[filter]},
   {"list", Dynamic[list]}
   }]]
```

[image]

I would advise moving to `ActionMenu` though, as it is much neater and designed for this type of thing (Mma V10.1 on Mac and Windows):

```
DynamicModule[{filter, list = 1},
 Column[{
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[filter], Range[6]],
   ActionMenu[Dynamic[list], 
    Table[With[{i = i}, 
      i :> (If[i < filter, list = list, list = i])], {i, 6}]],
   {"filter", Dynamic[filter]},
   {"list", Dynamic[list]}
   }]]
```

[image]

Comment: Neither of these work.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius it works on both my machines (Mma V10.1 on Mac and Windows). I do think that @Kuba's use of the second argument of `Dynamic` is a more elegant approach for `PopupMenu` though.

Comment: All it does is the last of the requirements: *"the item is grayed out, and the UI provides no affordance for clicking when the mouse is over the item: the cursor does not change, the item is not highlighted, and clicking produces no change at all (nothing happens)"*

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Kuba's answers, if you use `Dynamic` for both controls I believe you can fully accomplish your goal.

When you set ***filter*** it will both gray out the elements less than the ***filter*** in ***list*** and if the element in ***list*** is less than the ***filter*** it will reset it to the ***filter*** value.

```
Manipulate[
 {filter, list},

 (* Manipulate Controls *)

 {{filter, 1}, None},
 {{list,   2}, None},

 Grid[{
   {
    "Filter:",
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[filter, {(filter = #) &, (If[list < #, list = #]) &}],
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
     ]
    },
   {
    "List:",
    PopupMenu[
     Dynamic[list, 
      If[# < filter, , list = #] &], # -> 
        Dynamic[Style[#, If[# < filter, Gray, Black]]] & /@ {1, 2, 3, 
       4, 5, 6}
     ] (* end of PopupMenu *)
    } (* end of Row in Grid *)
   }] (* end of Grid *)

 ]
```

I don't know how to place figures in the answer where the popup menu is present (I'll ask Kuba and change the answer if I can learn how to do it). But if you try this I think you will see that it works the way you intended.

Comment: As with the other solutions, this misses: "... the UI provides no affordance for clicking when the mouse is over the item: the cursor does not change, the item is not highlighted ..."

Comment: When the cursor is over a grayed out item clicking has no effect. Changes only occur when a non-gray item is clicked. This is on windows. The color of the item gives one its enabled/disabled state.

Comment: Yes, but the item *highlights* when hovered over (at least on OS X).